# Loading by Ajax a plugin that also uses Ajax

Tags: plugins, ajax

I'm having problems with some "contact form" plugins whose use Ajax. The problem is that I use Ajax to call the plugin. Then the plugin is loaded, but when I try to submit the form, I'm redirected to this URL: `SITE/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`, when it should send the Ajax request, and only a `0` is printed on the window.

I think I'm using Ajax correctly:

`functions.php`:

```
function theme_name_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'mi-script-ajax',get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js/ajax-search.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'mi-script-ajax', 'MyAjax', array( 'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}


function llamadaAjax_callback() {
    $pageId = 0;
    $newSlug = '';
    $reviewSlug = '';
    $sPostType = 'any';
    $sTemplatePart = '';
    $sTaxonomy= false;

    //Busqueda
    if( isset(  $_POST['search'] ) ) {
        $sTemplatePart = 'search-ajax';
        $sPostType = 'any';
    }
    //Links
    elseif( isset(  $_POST['href'] ) ) {
        $pageId = preg_match( '/^http:\/\/.+\/\?page_id=\d+$/', $_POST['href'] ) ? substr( strrchr( $_POST['href'], '=' ), 1 ) : 'no-page' ;
        if( $pageId === 'no-page' && preg_match( '/^http:\/\/.+\/\?(news|reviews|entrevistas|radio_shows|podcasts|cat|tag)=[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+$/', $_POST['href'] ) ) {
            $newSlug = substr( strrchr( $_POST['href'], '=' ), 1 );
        } elseif( $pageId === 'no-page' && preg_match( '/^http:\/\/.+\/\?(artistas|sellos|generos)=[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+$/', $_POST['href'] ) ) {
            $sTaxonomy = true;
        }
        //$pageName = get_page_template_slug( intval( $pageId ) );
        if( $pageId !== 'no-page' ) {
            if( $pageId === '8' ) {
                $sPostType = 'any';
                $sTemplatePart = 'home-ajax';
            } elseif( $pageId === '22' ) { 
                $sPostType = 'reviews';
                $sTemplatePart = 'reviews-rvw-ajax';
            } elseif( $pageId === '6' ) {
                $sPostType = 'news';
                $sTemplatePart = 'noticias-news-ajax';
            } elseif( $pageId === '109' ) {
                $sPostType = 'entrevistas';
                $sTemplatePart = 'entrevistas-ajax';
            } elseif( $pageId === '112' ) {
                $sPostType = 'radio-shows';
                $sTemplatePart = 'radio-shows-ajax';
            } elseif( $pageId === '412' ) {
                $sTemplatePart = 'podcasts-ajax';
            } elseif( $pageId === '415' ) {
                $sTemplatePart = 'contacto-ajax';
            }

        } elseif( $sTaxonomy === true ) {
            $sTemplatePart = 'reviews-rvw-ajax';
            $sPostType = 'reviews'; 
        } elseif( $newSlug !== '' ) {
            $sTemplatePart = 'single-ajax';
            $sPostType = 'any';
            if( preg_match( '/^http:\/\/.+\/\?cat=\d+$/', $_POST['href'] ) ) {
                 $sTemplatePart = 'category-ajax';  
                 $sPostType = 'category';       
            } elseif( preg_match( '/^http:\/\/.+\/\?tag=[A-Za-z0-9\-]+$/', $_POST['href'] ) ) {
                 $sTemplatePart = 'tags-ajax';  
                 $sPostType = 'tag';        
            }

            //get_template_part( 'single-ajax' );
        }

    //Siguiente y Anterior
    } elseif( isset( $_POST['cadenaAll'] ) && ( isset( $_POST['cadenaPrev'] ) || isset( $_POST['cadenaNext'] ) ) ) {
        if( isset(  $_POST['pageName'] ) ) {
            if( $_POST['pageName'] === 'reviews' ) {
                $sPostType = 'reviews';
                $sTemplatePart = 'next_reviews-rvw-ajax';
            }
            elseif( $_POST['pageName'] === 'news' ) {
                $sPostType = 'news';
                $sTemplatePart = 'next_noticias-news-ajax';
            }
            elseif( $_POST['pageName'] === 'entrevistas' ) {
                $sPostType = 'entrevistas';
                $sTemplatePart = 'next_entrevistas-ajax';
            }
            elseif( $_POST['pageName'] === 'radio-shows' ) {
                $sPostType = 'radio-shows';
                $sTemplatePart = 'next_radio-shows-ajax';
            }
            elseif( $_POST['pageName'] === 'podcasts' ) {
                $sPostType = 'podcasts';
                $sTemplatePart = 'next_podcasts-ajax';
            }
            elseif( $_POST['pageName'] === 'categories' ) {
                $sPostType = 'category';
                $sTemplatePart = 'next_categories-ajax';
            }
            elseif( $_POST['pageName'] === 'tags' ) {
                $sPostType = 'tag';
                $sTemplatePart = 'next_tags-ajax';
            }
            elseif( $_POST['pageName'] === 'search' ) {
                $sPostType = 'any';
                $sTemplatePart = 'next_search-ajax';
            }
        }
    }


    //Submenu
    echo '<div id="submenu"><ul>';
    if( $sPostType !== '' ) {
        if( $sPostType == 'any' || $sPostType == 'category' || $sPostType == 'tag' ) {
            $allCategories = get_categories();
            foreach( $allCategories as $cat ) {
                echo '<li class="type-category"><a href="' . get_category_link( $cat->cat_ID ) . '">' . $cat->name . '</a></li>'; 
            }
        } else {

            global $wpdb;
            // set the target relationship here
            $post_type = $sPostType;
            $taxonomy = 'category';

            $terms_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
                SELECT
                    tt.term_id
                FROM
                    {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr,
                    {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt,
                    {$wpdb->posts} p
                WHERE 1=1
                    AND tr.object_id = p.id
                    AND p.post_type = '%s'
                    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
                    AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
                    AND tt.taxonomy ='%s'
                ", $post_type, $taxonomy ) );

            $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array(
                'include' => $terms_ids,
                'orderby' => 'name',
                'order' => 'ASC'
            ) );


             //$aTypeCategories = get_categories( array( 'post_type' => $type, 'number' => '10'  ) );
             foreach( $terms as $cat ) {
                echo '<li class="type-category"><a href="' . get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) . '">' . $cat->name . '</a></li>'; 
             }
        }
    } else {
        echo '<li class="type-category" style="color: transparent">Sin categorías</li>'; 
    }
    echo '</ul></div>';
    if( $sTemplatePart ) get_template_part($sTemplatePart);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
add_action('wp_ajax_llamadaAjax', 'llamadaAjax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_llamadaAjax', 'llamadaAjax_callback');
```

and in the `/js/ajax-search.js` file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var linksPages = $('.menu-menu-container a');

    linksPages.on('click',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#content').addClass('cortinaOut');
                if( !$(this).attr('href').match(/=8$/) ) {
                    $('#slider').fadeOut(800);
                }
                jQuery.post(MyAjax.url, {action : 'llamadaAjax' ,href : $(this).attr('href') }, function(response) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#content').html(response).fadeIn();
                    $('#content').removeClass('cortinaOut');
                }, 500);
            });
    });
});
```

I'm trying to found out the problem since two days ago. Any idea of how to solve it?

Comment: This is how the robot wars begin...

Comment: @ManoloSalsas I can see a number of potential problems right off of the bat. First a question: Are you ever registering your `ajax_callback()` function as an ajax handler with a call to `add_action()`? Your question doesn't show this step. Additionally, in what file is the first code block present? Is this in a plugin, or your theme's `functions.php`, or somewhere else entirely?

Comment: Also you mention you use Ajax to "load the plugin" but then it doesn't respond when you submit your form. I believe you're misinterpreting how WordPress loads... The entire platform and the necessary plugins must be loaded __on every request__ - as soon as the request is finished, everything leaves memory - this goes for AJAX requests as well; as soon as your AJAX request that calls the plugin finishes, the plugin is no longer available for any subsequent requests without loading it once more.

Comment: You show the JS, and the hooks, but where is the form itself?

Comment: Also can you check if your console has any messages? Set the console not to clear on page navigation encase you're missing something

Comment: @TomJNowell - It calls the `admin-ajax.php` file. The POST variables seem to be correct. But the response is `0`.

Comment: @TomJNowell - This is not a from, but a link, as you can see on the JQuery code.

Comment: @ManoloSalsas we cannot see your contact forms html, even if it is not a form but a link, we must see it, we cannot see a vital part of the puzzle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript is heavily reliant on inline attributes for event handling, rather than jQuery based event handling, and you're making AJAX calls to a different domain than the one you're currently on

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom, but my code has not syntax errors. The rest of the Ajax requests are working right. It is just the Contact Plugins that I've tried, the ones that don't work. The thing is that my Ajax code shouldn't affect to the plugin.

Comment: You haven't posted all of your code, please post all of your code if you want an answer that isn't based on second guessing

Comment: It's done. You can also check at the URL added to the question.

Comment: hmmm, I ***strongly*** recommend you remove all traces of stuff like 'onchange=""' etc, put all your javascript in javascript files and not inline in your HTML. Also your page has numerous js errors calling incorrect domains

Comment: I don't know what do you mean with this. I'm only putting my code in javascript files. It would be the contact form plugins. I'm thinking about searching for a no-Ajax plugin to do it, as I see it is maybe an error from the same plugins.

Comment: See the image I attached to my answer. Whatever plugin you're using, it's not good code. I recommend you go back to basics, implement a basic contact form with no captcha, and features such as AJAX step by step. There are thousands of tutorials on how to implement a contact form out there.

Comment: I know how to implement a form, but I'll try with other plugin without Ajax first. Thanks.

Comment: I would consider implementing the form yourself, if you know how, you would be saving time that you've otherwise spent hunting for a plugin without success.

Comment: I've finally done what you said. Implement my own form, since I've tried more plugins without success. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A number of problems are present here.

First and foremost, it appears that the first code block you posted is present in your `functions.php` file, or another theme file. If this is true, I urge you to consider WordPress's loading routine - themes are completely irrelevant to AJAX requests, and therefore WordPress will never touch any theme file of its own accord when processing an AJAX requests. What I'm getting at is that if that code is indeed in a theme file, then the `ajax_callback()` function is not available to WordPress when it's processing AJAX requests.

The next problem is that `ajax_callback()` never seems to get registered as an AJAX handler. In order to do so, you need to register the function with a custom action prefixed with `wp_ajax_` and/or `wp_ajax_nopriv` [as described in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29), with the complete action format `wp_ajax_{custom action name}` and/or `wp_ajax_nopriv_{custom action name}`. Doing so would look similar to the following (if not present in a plugin class):

```
function ajax_callback() {
  ...
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_custom_action', 'ajax_callback' );        // For registered users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_custom_action', 'ajax_callback' ); // For unregistered users
```

If this code is not in a plugin class or PHP namespace, I ***highly*** recommend that you use a more descriptive name than `ajax_callback` in order to remove the possibility of naming collisions.

If this code **is** in a plugin class or PHP namespace, the second argument of `add_action` needs to be modified to fit the appropriate [PHP callback format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Finally, in your posted JavaScript the `action` key is set to `ajax`. This key is what tells WordPress which registered AJAX handler to execute. As it stands, your JavaScript function would invoke WordPress to attempt to execute any handlers registered to the `wp_ajax_ajax` action. If your AJAX callback is indeed registered to this action, I recommend you change it as `wp_ajax_ajax` is excessively generic and has a high probability of resulting in naming collisions (if not general confusion).

The `action` key should be set to the `{custom action name}` portion of the action(s) referenced above. In order to call the `ajax_callback()` function as registered to the `wp_ajax_my_custom_action`/`wp_ajax_nopriv_my_custom_action` actions as done above, the `action` key in your AJAX request should be `my_custom_action`.

I recommend that you read the [Codex entry on AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) for a better understanding of how AJAX works in WordPress.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. However, I was already registering the Ajax callback. I've tried replacing the so generic callback function name, but no success. Remember that Ajax is working fine with all other links. I've updated my question.

Comment: I've updated my question. Maybe now you're able to see the problem.